# What is the default size limit of a wxstring (and can it be changed)?

Tags: string, limit, wxstring

I working with an app that has a side app build with WxWidgets.  I suspect there's a limit to string size, but I'm having trouble proving/determining that.  Most of the docs say to use std::string instead, but I don't have time frame to rewrite the whole app if needed, so I'm just trying to find out if there's a simple way to determine (and possible enlarge, or find alternative to) the size.

FYI, App written in C, wxWidget version not immediately known but hopefully recently current.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I have not looked into all the deatils, but a quick browse of the source code (version 3.0.2) shows that the implementation of `wxString` is quite similar to that of many C++ `string`s, using a dynamic buffer to store the contants. Hence, the theoretical size is only limited by the maximum value that a `size_t` variable can reach (typically 4 GB on a 32-bit architecture, a lot more on 64-bit), which is exactly the same limit that `std::string` has.